# Laravel: How to decide using server.php or public/index.php

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel’ server.php and public/index.php are do the same thing, server.php is just require the public/index.php. So in my Apache http.conf file, I can use server.php or public/index.php in DirectoryIndex, and also can set the DocumentRoot to the project root folder or the project’s public folder. The question is which case should I use the right configuration, and how to use it.

Comment: You should always point your apache's DirectoryIndex to your project's index which is public/index.php on your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment in the `server.php` file explains it's purpose -

> This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel application without having installed a "real" web server software here.

So if you're using Apache, use `public/index.php`.

Answer (score 4):

The *server.php* file is used with the `serve` Artisan command to start a lightweight webserver using PHP's internal webserver:

```
$ php artisan serve --port=8000 
Laravel development server started: <http://localhost:8000>
```

...which is equivalent to running the following command from the project's root directory:

```
$ php -S localhost:8000 -t public/ ../server.php
```

This is intended for *simple* development and prototyping only when we may not have or need a separate webserver yet, and production webservers should always direct requests to the *index.php* file in the *public/* directory.